# What is a business contact?

Tags: networking

I Googled this and can't find much detail. Sometimes a person will refer to someone to whom they call a "business contact." I have also been told that, in order to succeed in business at a larger scale, I'll need "business contacts."

My basic line of questioning goes something like:

**What is a business contact?**

**How do you make business contacts?**

**How does a business contact help one succeed, either in the workplace/business in general?**

Comment: Its merely someone you know from a business or work connection, as opposed to a social or familial link.  Someone who does a good job, but you're not necessarily friends with them.

Answer (score 2):

Business contact can mean:

1.Someone you work with/know in a business whom is a contact for business/work purposes.

2.Someone you know who works in a business (not necessarily with you) that you have as a contact.

That's really all there is to it. When someone says they have a business contact, they mean they either work with someone in a specific field/interest, or know someone who does that they have a connection with, such as someone who may provide assistance, mentoring, services, etc.

For example, a website development company or individual running a website business can make a contact with a web designer for either advice, service, tutorials, all of the above, or etc.

Answer (score 0):

Leave business aside take a day to day example

> You went college you knew no one there but as the time passed you came
>   to have some friends and got in contact with many and as the time
>   passed ,those contacts came up to help you at some point when you
>   needed some support(They could be friends or friends of friends) .

Similarly in business to survive the competition you'll need some support from the ones in the industry and that's what business contacts are meant for.
These contacts may help you when looking for leads or recruiting contacts or you need some Business profiles, Direct dial numbers, Email and more.
Employee directories by name, function or location.

All the above things are included in business contacts and you can use them to solve the problem either with their experience or their services.